# $\mathbb{Z} / n\mathbb{Z}$ is semisiple iff $n$ is square free and $n>1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

I have that a module $M$ is semisimple if and only if $M$ has a semisimple decomposition, i.e, if there are simple submodules $\{ T_\alpha \}_{\alpha \in A}$ of $M$ such that
$$
  M = \bigoplus_{\alpha \in A} X_α T_\alpha \,.
$$

What I've been trying to do is:

I know that if $n = p_1^{e_1} \dotsm p_n^{e_n}$, then
$$
  \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}
  \cong
  \mathbb{Z}/p_1^{e_1}\mathbb{Z}
  \times \dotsb \times
  \mathbb{Z}/p_n^{e_n}\mathbb{Z} \,.
$$
And if $n$ is square free, then $e_i=1$ for all $i$. But I don't know what else should I do, I've been trying. :(
Any help? I also don't know how to begin the converse.

Comment: You almost finish. If $p$ is a prime number, $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ is a simple $\Bbb Z$-module.

Comment: Then $\mathbb{Z}_n=\oplus_{i=1}^n \mathbb{Z}/p_i\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Isomorphism, not equality: $\Bbb Z_n \cong \bigoplus_i \Bbb Z/p_i\Bbb Z$. Prove that if $\{S_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in A}$ is a family of simple modules, then the external direct sum $\bigoplus_{\alpha \in A} S_\alpha$ is semisimple; and prove that any isomorphic module to a semisimple module is semisimple.

Comment: Thank you! And to see that $n$ is square free, do you have any hint?

Comment: @SamantaGuzmán consider non-square free component $M=\mathbb{Z}/p^e\mathbb{Z}$, $e>1$ of your $R=\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. Note that it is an ideal, and thus a module over $R$. But is it semi simple? I.e. is every submodule of $M$ its direct summand?